# using SQL and PL/SQL i'm trying to find the sixth day from today

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out the day like fifth day or sixth day from today using a query.
For ex today is `15/11/2013---Friday`. If i give this as input i should get

```
fifth day-- 20/11/2013--Wednesday
sixth day---21/11/2013---Thursday
```

Comment: You don't need PL/SQL, plain Oracle SQL is enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    sysdate as now,
    trunc(sysdate) as today,
    trunc(sysdate) + 5 as fifth_day,
    trunc(sysdate) + 6 as sixth_day
FROM DUAL
```

You could also replace `trunc(sysdate)` with a parameter if you wish

```
:p_Date + 5 as fifth_day
```

Comment: this really helps,thank you. I'd be glad if you help me to find the same using PL/SQL too

Comment: This is Oracle SQL, which is a part of PL/SQL. If you add a number to a date-value in Oracle, you add that many days to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEADD()` function... you can use as follows:

```
DECLARE @enddate datetime
select @enddate = dateadd(day,6,GETDATE())

select @enddate
```

Comment: That is invalid for Oracle (and it's not even standard SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

> `select sysdate+6 from dual;`

if like to know as day

> `select to_char(to_date(trunc(sysdate+6),'dd-mm-yy'),'day') from dual;`